# D365 F&O : In X++, reduce bit-depth of PNG file from 24 bits to 1 bit

Tags: png, x++, zpl

We need to print PNG images with a bit depth of 24 bits on a Zebra printer.
So we have to convert the PNG to ZPL.

I have done it in the PNG's current bit depth pf 24 bits, generated the ZPL, but the
Labelary online ZPL viewer rejects the ZPL, saying memory ran out.

I assume that this is because the PNG bit depth is 24, when it only needs to be 1 for a black and white label.
That should give a much smaller ZPL string.

So I need some code to reduce the bit depth, in X++, the coding language for Dynamics 365 F&O.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Using other tools like Photoshop is out of the question, because we need it in code, and it must run without human input.

My current X++ code is:

```
  binData=new BinData();
  binData.setData(BinData::loadFromBase64(_base64Png));

  pngSize=bindata.size();

  // Get a representation of the binary PNG data in hex
  hexStr=BinData::dataToString(binData.getData());
```

zpl='^XA~DYE:LABEL.PNG,p,p,'+fmtint(pngSize)+',40,'+hexStr+'^XA^FO0,0^IME:UKMAIL-LABEL.PNG^FS^XZ';

But the above does not reduce the bit depth of the PNG first.

Thanks for any coding assistance.

Comment: You can do it with **ImageMagick** if you can shell out to it with a `system()` call, e.g. `magick INPUT.PNG -type bilevel output.png` or you can make an 8-bit palettte image with `magick INPUT.PNG PNG8:output.png`